# Grouped moving average with new time window in R

Tags: r, moving-average

A minimal example would be:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep("P1", 100),
                 treatment = c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 50)),
                 t = rep(seq(1:50), 2),
                 x = rnorm(n = 100))
```

which, let's imagine, is some value measured each second. Now I would also want to have the average of each 20 second window. so `1-20`, `21-40`, ... (i.e. no overlap)

My actual data has a column `ID` representing multiple subjects, `treatment` with labels for two treatments and the actual time column is in increments of 5 (0, 5, 10, 15, 20). There are other important grouping columns. The values I have are from EEG recordings and I need to increase the size of window for some analyses.

What would be cleanest way to do this? Note that there must be a way of knowing which time-window the calculated average relates to (just 20, 40 would be enough, not a string with 1-20).

EDIT:
based on a now deleted comment I got here

```
df %>%
  mutate(timeWin = ceiling(.$t/20)*20) %>%
  group_by(ID, treatment, timeWin) %>%
  summarise(xAvg = mean(x))
```

Only issue with that bit of code is the rather crude use of `ceiling`. In the example above the 40-50 bracket will be printed as 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$grouped_time = ave(df$t, ceiling(df$t/20), FUN = max)
aggregate(df["x"], df[c("ID", "treatment", "grouped_time")], mean)
#  ID treatment grouped_time           x
#1 P1         A           20  0.19192002
#2 P1         B           20  0.27873536
#3 P1         A           40 -0.27099180
#4 P1         B           40  0.01661547
#5 P1         A           50 -0.02021535
#6 P1         B           50 -0.08719458
```